# Grid column width not respected when inside of a ScrollViewer

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've one view of mine which displays a control based on some factory:

```
<dxdo:LayoutPanel ShowCaption="False">
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ContentControl Margin="15,5,10,10" Content="{Binding SomeObject, Converter={StaticResource ModelToViewModelConverter}}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ConventionBasedDataTemplateSelector}" />
    </ScrollViewer>
</dxdo:LayoutPanel>
```

One of the control that is displayed contains one Grid, with some specific controls.

Basically I've the 2 firsts columns that are used with specific sizes and a third one to take the remaining available space, and then some components that takes the whole width:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ch.VibroMeter.Xms.Configurators.Common.Views.Machinery.MachineStates.CustomMachineStateView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             <!-- skipping namespace declaration -->
             mc:Ignorable="d" >
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <converters:DrawingColorToMediaColorConverter x:Key="DrawingColorToMediaColorConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
      <StackPanel>
            <controls:TitleBlock Title="{Binding State.Name}" Margin="0,0,0, 5" />

            <subControls:MainProperties Model="{Binding State, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=False}" />

            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Source={x:Static common:Constants.COLUMN_LABEL_WIDTH}}" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Source={x:Static common:Constants.COLUMN_FIELD_WIDTH}}" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <!--Color-->
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Color" Margin="3" />
                <dxe:PopupColorEdit Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" ShowAlphaChannel="False" Margin="3" Color="{Binding State.Color, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource DrawingColorToMediaColorConverter}}" />

                <!--Separator-->
                <Separator Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="0,12,0,12"/>

                <!--Measurements Filters -->
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Conditions" FontSize="18" Margin="3,3,3,12"/>

                <measurementsFilterConfigurationControl:MeasurementsFilterConfigurationControl Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                    FilterRuleTypes="{Binding AvailableFilterRuleTypes}"
                    MeasurementsFilterConfiguration="{Binding State.FilterConfiguration}" 
                    Margin="0 10 0 0"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

I found out that the columns sizes are not at all respected. The COLUMN_LABEL_WIDTH is 200,  but the `ActualWidth` of my `TextBlock` with "Color" text is more than 300.

After some investigation, I found out that if I remove the `ScrollViewer` or set the HorizontalScrollBarVisibility to Disabled, it works, but then when I resize the window too much(for this control, less than COLUMN_LABEL_WIDTH +COLUMN_FIELD_WIDTH), I don't get the desired scrollbars.

I understand that when I use a scrollViewer, I will get an infinite available size, but I would have thought this space would have been put in the column with the `*` size.

I cannot removing the scrollViewer Auto, because some components(like the `MeasurementsFilterConfigurationControl` in this view) might get hidden when resizing the windows).

I don't have access to the ScrollViewer in this component.

So how would you fix this?

Comment: `ColumnDefinition.Width` is of type `GridLength` not `double`. What type is `common:Constants.COLUMN_LABEL_WIDTH`? I am not sure if you can bind to a double or other numeric value. Also DependencyProperties for measurements are kind of proposals, the actual value depends on multiple additional values.

Comment: yes, I know, but if you reference it through the Source:{Static xxx}, it works(otherwise I get binding error. But anyway, I tried by hardcoding those values, doesn't change anything.

Comment: ok. if you comment out the 'MeasurementsFilterConfigurationControl' (with ColumnSpan=3) does it help?

Comment: If I want fixed column width if usually set MinWidth and MaxWidth to the same value...

Comment: @lidqy disabling MeasurementsFilterConfigurationControl didn't have an effect, but setting the Min/MaxWidth does. Why would the Width not be respected but the min/max width would?